# Do we really need the [syntax] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

I think [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax) makes no sense if you don't specify the language you're talking about. I also think that if I have a doubt about how to structure something in a language, or what something means or how it works, the language's own tag should be enough.

I have been looking at the questions marked with [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax) and I feel that they would be just as meaningful if they didn't have it.

Even among some questions that have many upvotes, I think the tag is irrelevant to the question itself. [This one, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274892/how-do-you-connect-to-multiple-mysql-databases-on-a-single-webpage).

Is there a good reason for the tag to exist? I would like to be proven wrong on my thoughts about this one, specially since there are *over 9000* questions marked with it.

Answer (score 12):

I see where the syntax tag could be useful: compiler theory and computer languages. Perhaps the tag is being abused, which means that it should be cleaned up rather than burninated. When I use [lex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lex) and [yacc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yacc) there can be some legitimate moments where [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax) can be useful

Answer (score 10):

The tag [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax) has a clear meaning — it's about syntax, which is a clear, well-known concept in programming. When I look through the questions in that tag, I see a lot of questions that are about syntax.

Sure, there are questions that misuse the tag. [Now there's one less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274892/how-do-you-connect-to-multiple-mysql-databases-on-a-single-webpage). There are also plenty of questions that are tagged [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) even though they're only about one of the languages, or questions tagged [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) or [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) that are really about PHP or JavaScript. That's no reason to remove the tags [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) or [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery).

Comment: By this standard, potentially *every* programming question could be tagged with [tag:syntax]. Unless you're writing a language or working on a compiler, the [tag:syntax] tag is going to be prone to regular abuse. It seems to me that it is most often used by beginner developers who aren't even familiar with the word "syntax" in regular language. In turn, they add the tag to a question because it appears in their error message and don't understand what it means. So the tag should probably go.

Comment: @cloudworks No, most programming questions have nothing to do with syntax. What's the proportion of misuse? If it's very high, that may be a good reason to get rid of the tag, but just being *sometimes* misused is no reason to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Having a tag be prone to abuse is reason enough to get rid of it, else there will be this constant battle to keep the tag un-abused. To me, this particular tag is not worth keeping. Maybe it should be replaced by [parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parsing) (or [syntax-parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax-parsing)).

Comment: No, having a tag be prone to abuse is *not* reason enough to get rid of it. *Language* tags are misused all the time; should we get rid of [tag:c#] or [tag:java] then?