# We don't need to use [semicolon];

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, retag-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

At the time of writing, there are 301 questions tagged [semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/semicolon), but no one is actually following the tag. This makes sense, since you can hardly be an expert in semicolons. They work entirely differently in many languages and are only a tiny fraction of most languages' syntax.

I propose that [semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/semicolon) should be burninated or possibly re-tagged to / made a synonym of [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax).

An example of where the semicolon tag comes close to being valid is *[What does the leading semicolon in JavaScript libraries do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873983/what-does-the-leading-semicolon-in-javascript-libraries-do)*.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207818/who-needs-punctuation-we-should-just-destroy-all-of-these-tags-now-can-we-please

Comment: I suspect almost every question so tagged could be closed as "a simple typographic error".

Comment: Does JavaScript's semicolon insertion deserve a tag of its own?  (I don't do JS, just occasionally see people citing semicolon insertion as a misfeature.)

Comment: How many people actually know how to use a semicolon; anyway?

Comment: maybe merge it with `colon` ? There's a whole medical discipline that evolves around that one

Comment: I do think we could need a tag for [automatic semicolon insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=automatic+semicolon+insertion) in JS.

Comment: Burninate it so I can finally change my product name to `semicolon`

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q: +112/-4; A1 (Saying yes): +90/-4;

Comment: "end of the line for [semicolon]"

Comment: Give this tag a [semicolon]oscopy.

Comment: Yes, we should burninate the semicolon tag.

Comment: Hmm, no-one is watching it you say; well not no more! ;-D... though I'll try to be ready with marshmallows when the mob arrives.

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q: +184/-5. A1 (Saying Yes): +135/-6. A2 (Saying Yes): +18/0. The community has voted in favor of the burnination

Comment: At some point, the [tag:colon] and [tag:comma] tags should be given the same "burnination" treatment as [tag:semicolon] is currently getting — and for the same reason.  Some medical doctors specialize in the treatment of diseases of the colon, but programmers don't.

Comment: I also came across the [tag:backslash] tag — it might need attention too (1 watcher, ~750 questions).

Answer (score 135):

The tag has no value, and should be burninated.

It should not be made a synonym of [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax) however. That tag is probably a meta-tag, and has a [burninate request of its own](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262342/do-we-really-need-the-syntax-tag).

I'd prefer not to re-tag to [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax); simply retag it to the relevant language.

Looking at the [criteria for tag burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191), we find the following for [semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/semicolon):

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is
    applied? And is it unambiguous?**

The tag is ambiguous. The use of a semicolon depends on the language under discussion. It could also be about semicolons in Unicode, or other character encoding schemes.

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Partially, in the sense that many programming languages have some rules for semicolons. But this is covered by the tags for these languages. Or, if it is about how some encoding scheme uses semicolons, it should be the tag for that particular coding scheme. But questions about semicolons themselves aren't on-topic.

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No. A question about the use of semicolons in Java is a Java question. A question about the use of semicolons in JSON is a JSON question. And so on.

**4.  Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No. Ok, it means "semicolon", but as discussed, the meaning of this differs per language.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, one thing that speaks for the syntax tag is that it tells you something valuable when it's used in combination with a language tag, but that's a discussion we shouldn't have here I suppose.

Comment: @overactor If the meaning of a tag depends on other tags, it is a meta-tag. But we can have that discussion on the linked burninate-request for [tag:syntax].

Comment: Unicode; Ooh, the Greek question mark!

Comment: @S.L.Barth [semicolon] doesn't even really depend consistently on other tags to derive its meaning. Forth, Factor, and friends use it to end a word definition. OCaml and J use it like most C-style languages use a comma. I see this as not much different than a [space] tag in a linguistics SE site. That space could be a paragraph separator, a word separator, or even to *optionally* delimit a number from its abbreviated unit of measure. And such a tag is just noise.

Sounds burninatible enough to me.

Comment: Another set of criteria is based on top users: are there any who are consistently answering questions in the tag.  The answer's "not really".  Mr Skeet shows up with 7 answers and 39 up-votes; CMS has 3 answers and 426 up-votes.  But there's no real expert showing up.  And there've not been many answers in the last 30 days, or many questions, come to that.  All the top askers have a single question (one with 169 up-votes — truly remarkable!).  This information also indicates that the tag should be burninated. These criteria were suggested to me by Bill the Lizard back in his days as moderator.

Comment: I have an incredibly large issue when I see a [Python question about semicolons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35305426/semicolon-drives-python-crazy)... We don't use semi colons! Chances are though, if the question is about a bug and the issue is a semicolon, it should probably be closed as a typographical error anyway then.

Comment: I wouldn't reference a burniation-request from two years ago with 2 upvotes as a reason not to merge. [Syntax] will stay. A merge sounds reasonable.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs It's also [meta-tag:status-declined].

Answer (score 22):

I started writing an answer in order to defend the [semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/semicolon) tag, as it had a very specific syntactic usage but I had to change my mind multiple times. I feel that this tag has to be burninated. Along with the reasons that SL Barth has already mentioned in their answer, I found a couple of other issues (tag-smells) which relate to the tag not being used in the proper sense:

- Most of the [top users in the tag have answered just one or two questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/semicolon/topusers). This shows that there are no top users who can discuss about the need of the tag. As Steve [mentions in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276924/we-dont-need-your-approval-any-more/380480#comment672778_380480), a tag that doesn't attract enough knowledgable users is probably not a great tag.
- There are just 3 watchers of the tag, which means that there are no users to curate the tag on a day to day basis.

Now coming to the retags:

- We need to create a new tag for the JavaScript's Automatic Semicolon Insertion as mentioned by [Bergi in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317245/should-we-burninate-the-semicolon-tag#comment311448_317245), who is a top user (and has a gold badge) in that tag.

  > I do think we could need a tag for [automatic semicolon insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=automatic+semicolon+insertion) in JS.
- Most of the questions where it is related to the syntactical usage of the semicolon tag *can* be tagged with [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax) instead. I agree with [Angelo's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317245/should-we-burninate-the-semicolon-tag#comment311697_317249) on Barth's post)
- In many questions, [semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/semicolon) has been used just because the question contains something very vaguely related to semicolons. Like CSV file with semicolon delimiter, or semicolon in a string, and so on. Here the tag is not necessary at all and can be removed.
- In the questions also tagged with a few major languages, apart from the positively scored questions, most of the others are related to typographical error of adding/not adding a semicolon. These can just be closed as "No longer reproducible"

I also don't feel that [semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/semicolon) should be merged with [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax), at the end. The tag should be just removed.

Comment: I agree; this is a bit similar to [tag:ampersand] tag: `&` is a command separator, so questions about this case should be tagged [tag:syntax], like [tag:semicolon] and questions that just contain it or have a title like `Why can't I put an ampersand/semicolon here?`, etc. should not be tagged at all. So, I think that the semicolon tag should be burninated.

Comment: Why should there be a separate tag for automatic semicolon insertion? As long as no other common languages have it, it's exclusively a part of Javascript and Javascript syntax.

Comment: @Zev creating tags for standard concepts even if they relate to just one programming language is fine. See [tag:gil], which is just for python.

Answer (score 11):

[semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/semicolon) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Use, [automatic-semicolon-insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automatic-semicolon-insertion) for questions related to [automatic semicolon insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=automatic+semicolon+insertion) in JavaScript.
- Use [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax) for  questions where it is related to the syntactical usage of the semicolon tag.
- Remove the [semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/semicolon) from questions where the semicolon is being used in a string, or as a separator, or a delimiter.

## Progress:

The [semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/semicolon) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=semicolon),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsemicolon%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsemicolon%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsemicolon%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsemicolon%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track the progress of the burnination!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190474)

[Dashboard for progress](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=317245)

[image: burnination progress chart]

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/semicolon) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/semicolon) tag — just flag/vote to close the question.

#### [Do not downvote questions in order to trigger roomba](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307009)

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/semicolon) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: I think that the stats counting is grossly underestimating the effort I've put in — it says '7' when I looked just now, but I think it is more like "in excess of 50" (and I think that's still understating it — I just counted 87 edits where I'd used the comment "Semicolon tag is being burninated" or equivalent wording, though I accept that could be off by a couple).

Comment: There were some issues last week with it syncing up with chat. It now shows that you did 83.. it's maintained by Rob (another mod), I'll ask them if the issue was fixed. Thanks for reporting it. :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That was my bad. The application experienced a few authentication issues - I've got it to re-process the burnination so your statistics should be accurate now

Comment: @Rob — it’s seemed to be up to date for a while now, but was not when I commented late last night.  Thanks for resolving the problems.  And thanks to Bhargav for relaying the info.